# Create a joined Key-Value in LinqToSql

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, aspxgridview

I have a GridView binded to LinqToSql-DataSource. The DataSource is Multiple-Join. I need unique Key-Values for the Grid. But all PrimaryKeys from the Tables could exist double or not because of left joins.

I have solved the problem in a pure sql-statement. There i create a ID for the TableRows by joining two PrimaryKeys an connecting with a "-". I need one of the IDs for later working with TableRows, the other could be null.

So I do in SQL-Statement:

```
select CAST(mitgliedschaft.id as varchar(MAX)) + '-' + CAST(ISNULL(funktion.id, '') as varchar(MAX)) as id from ...... inner join ...... etc
```

I need the CASTS for not producing Calculating with the "-" and the ISNULL-Function because the second ID could be Null.

Now I have to transfer this part of the scenario into Linq-Statement. I tried like this:

```html
...
...
select new
       {
           ...
           id = mitgliedschaft.id.ToString() + "-" + (funktion.id == null ? 0 : funktion.id).ToString()
           ...

       });
```

But didn't get it running in that way. Can someone help me concatenating an ID with "-" and an ID that can be NULL? If it is NULL it should be an empty String or Null-Digit or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

got it now:

```html
select new
{
  id = (mitgliedschaft.id.ToString() + "-") + (funktion.id.ToString() ?? "0")
}
```